# ¿Cómo repetir el ID en múltiples registros en diferentes tablas de una base de datos?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, formularios

[image: Base de datos relacionada][image: Pantalla de creación de proyectos]

¿Qué tal a todos?

Soy nuevo en la programación de páginas web y actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una página que sirva para gestionar proyectos.

He logrado crear dos formularios dinámicos (lista de materiales y actividades) que agregan "n" número de campos. Y otro formulario "estático" que lo componen las secciones de información, tiempo total y costo total. El problema con el que me enfrento actualmente es el siguiente: al dar clic en el botón "save" se guardan los formularios en diferentes tablas en una misma base de datos (formulario estático en una tabla, formulario dinámico de lista de materiales en otra tabla, etc.), pero lo que busco es, que al hacer clic en "save"se guarden todos los registros que se hayan agregado en los formularios dinámicos de lista de materiales y actividades con el mismo id del formulario estático, es decir, que repita el id del proyecto en cada material y actividad que se agreguen.

Les comparto mi código (siéntanse con la libertad de usarlo, si les es de utilidad) HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link class="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

#barra_lateral {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#contenedor {
    position: absolute;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 15%;
    top: "0%";
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#encabezado_gris {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#encabezado_azul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #00CCFF;
}
#encabezado_verde {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    top: 15%;
    background-color: #00FFCC;
    z-index: 4;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#zona_material {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 35%;
    top: 21%;
    left: 31%;
    background-color: #49D6C8;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 2.5%;
}
#zona_info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    height: 35%;
    top: 21%;
    left: 0.5%;
    background-color: #49D6C8;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 2.5%;
}
#zona_tiempo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 18%;
    height: 17%;
    top: 21%;
    left: 81.5%;
    background-color: #49D6C8;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 2.5%;
}
#zona_costo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 18%;
    height: 17%;
    top: 39%;
    left: 81.5%;
    background-color: #49D6C8;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 2.5%;
}
#zona_actividades {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 40%;
    top: 57%;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: #49D6C8;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 1%;
}
#titulo_informacion {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 15%;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nombre_proyecto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 15%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #CCC;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#descripcion_proyecto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 35%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #CCC;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#supervisor_asignado {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 15%;
    top: 70%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #CCC;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#numero_proyecto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 75%;
    left: 55%;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 3%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #CCC;
    overflow:auto;
}
#titulo_materiales {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 15%;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#contenedor_lmateriales {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 15%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#titulo_tiempo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#tiempo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 45%;
    left: 5%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #CCC;
}
#titulo_costo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#costo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 45%;
    left: 5%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #CCC;
}
#contenedor_lactividades {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 15%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#titulo_actividades {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 15%;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#contenedor_guardar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 80%;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 95%;
    top: 15%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#titulo_cproyectos {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 1%;
    z-index: 5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#contenedor_logout {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 1;
    left: 1;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#contenedor_foto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color:#F00;
}
#contenedor_rango {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 80%;
    background-color:#F90;
}
#contenedor_menus {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 20%;
    background-color: #006699;
    overflow: auto;
}

}
  #barra_lateral #contenedor_menus #”button” li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #000;
}
a:link {
    color: #999999;
}
a:visited {
    color: #999999;
}
a:hover {
    color: #0CF;
}


#menu_au {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 15%;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.estilo_titulo_au {
    color: #FFF;
}
#submenu_au {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 95%;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 5%;
    top: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#menu_descargas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 20%;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5;
}
#titulo_menu_au {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 15%;
    z-index: 5;
    color: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#titulo_menu_descargas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 15%;
    z-index: 5;
    color: #FFF;
    left: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#submenu_descargas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 95%;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 5%;
    top: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#contenedor_home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 80%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-size:xx-large;
}
#alto_editable_descripcion{height:70%;
    }
</style>

<div id="barra_lateral">
    <div id="contenedor_foto">
      <div id="contenedor_home"><a href="welcome.php" title="Home"><center><strong>Home</strong></center></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor_rango"></div>
  <div id="contenedor_menus">
    <div id="menu_au">
        <div id="titulo_menu_au">Administrador de usuarios</div>
        <div id="submenu_au">
            <ul id=”administrador_usuarios”>
                <li><a href=registro_usuarios.php>Registrar usuario</a></li>
                 <li><a href="modificar_usuarios.php">Modficar usuario</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Eliminar usuario</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu_descargas">
      <div id="titulo_menu_descargas">Descargas</div>
      <div id="submenu_descargas">
            <ul id=”administrador_usuarios”>
                <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Rendimiento</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="encabezado_gris">
    <div id="titulo_cproyectos"><strong>Creacion de proyectos</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div id="encabezado_azul"></div>
  <div id="encabezado_verde">
    <div id="contenedor_guardar">
    <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="zona_info">
    <div id="titulo_informacion"><strong>Informacion</strong></div>
    <div id="nombre_proyecto">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_nombre">
        <th width="15%" height="15%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">Nombre</th>
        <td height="15%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="nombre_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div id="descripcion_proyecto">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_descripcion">
        <th width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Descripcion</center></th>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="descripcion_proyecto"></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     </div>
    <div id="supervisor_asignado">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_supervisor">
        <th width="15%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Supervisor</center></th>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="supervisor_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="zona_material">
    <div id="titulo_materiales"><strong>Lista de materiales</strong></div>
        <div id="contenedor_lmateriales">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
             <tr>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Material</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Responsable</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Descripcion</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Costo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Tiempo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="5%">Acciones</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_name"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_code"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_desc"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_price"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_time"></td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" >+</button></td>
             </tr>
            </table>

       </div>
  </div>
<div id="zona_tiempo">
    <div id="titulo_tiempo"><strong><center>Tiempo total</center></strong></div>
    <div id="tiempo">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_supervisor">
        <th width="15%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Tiempo</center></th>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="tiempo_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="zona_costo">
    <div id="titulo_costo"><strong><center>Costo total</center></strong></div>
    <div id="costo">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_supervisor">
        <th width="15%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Costo</center></th>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="costo_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="zona_actividades">
    <div id="titulo_actividades"><strong>Actividades</strong></div>
<div id="contenedor_lactividades">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_tablea">
             <tr>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Actividad</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Tipo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Descripcion</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Tiempo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Responsable</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="5%">Acciones</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_act"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_tipo"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_desca"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_timea"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_respa"></td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><button type="button" name="adda" id="adda" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" >+</button></td>
             </tr>
            </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 $('#add').click(function(){
  count = count + 1;
  var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_name'></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_code'></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_desc'></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_price' ></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_time' ></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#F0F0F0' valign='middle' align='center'><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";   
   html_code += "</tr>";  
   $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
  $('#' + delete_row).remove();
 });

 $('#save').click(function(){
  var item_name = [];
  var item_code = [];
  var item_desc = [];
  var item_price = [];
  var item_time = [];
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   item_name.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_code').each(function(){
   item_code.push($(this).list());
  });
  $('.item_desc').each(function(){
   item_desc.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_price').each(function(){
   item_price.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_time').each(function(){
   item_time.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert2.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{item_name:item_name, item_code:item_code, item_desc:item_desc, item_price:item_price, item_time:item_time},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
 });

 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 fetch_item_data();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 $('#adda').click(function(){
  count = count + 1;
  var html_codea = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_act'></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_tipo'></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_desca'></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_timea' ></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_respa' ></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#F0F0F0' valign='middle' align='center'><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";   
   html_codea += "</tr>";  
   $('#crud_tablea').append(html_codea);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
  $('#' + delete_row).remove();
 });

 $('#save').click(function(){
  var item_act = [];
  var item_tipo = [];
  var item_desca = [];
  var item_timea = [];
  var item_respa = [];
  $('.item_act').each(function(){
   item_act.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_tipo').each(function(){
   item_tipo.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_desca').each(function(){
   item_desca.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_timea').each(function(){
   item_timea.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_respa').each(function(){
   item_respa.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{item_act:item_act, item_tipo:item_tipo, item_desca:item_desca, item_timea:item_timea, item_respa:item_respa},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
 });

 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 fetch_item_data();

$('#save').click(function(){
  var nombre_proyecto = [];
  var descripcion_proyecto = [];
  var supervisor_proyecto = [];
  var tiempo_proyecto = [];
  var costo_proyecto = [];
  $('.nombre_proyecto').each(function(){
   nombre_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.descripcion_proyecto').each(function(){
   descripcion_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.supervisor_proyecto').each(function(){
   supervisor_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.tiempo_proyecto').each(function(){
   tiempo_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.costo_proyecto').each(function(){
   costo_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert3.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{nombre_proyecto:nombre_proyecto, descripcion_proyecto:descripcion_proyecto, supervisor_proyecto:supervisor_proyecto, tiempo_proyecto:tiempo_proyecto, costo_proyecto:costo_proyecto},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
 });

 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 fetch_item_data();

});
</script>
```

Y mis códigos PHP (3):

```
<?php
//insert.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if(isset($_POST["item_act"]))
{
 $item_act = $_POST["item_act"];
 $item_tipo = $_POST["item_tipo"];
 $item_desca = $_POST["item_desca"];
 $item_timea = $_POST["item_timea"];
 $item_respa = $_POST["item_respa"];
 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($item_act); $count++)
 {
  $item_act_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_act[$count]);
  $item_tipo_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_tipo[$count]);
  $item_desca_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_desca[$count]);
  $item_timea_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_timea[$count]);
  $item_respa_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_respa[$count]);
  if($item_act_clean != '' && $item_tipo_clean != '' && $item_desca_clean != '' && $item_timea_clean != '' && $item_respa_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO item(item_act, item_tipo, item_desca, item_timea, item_respa) 
   VALUES("'.$item_act_clean.'", "'.$item_tipo_clean.'", "'.$item_desca_clean.'", "'.$item_timea_clean.'", "'.$item_respa_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Item Data Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All Fields are Required';
 }
}
?>

<?php
//insert2.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if(isset($_POST["item_name"]))
{
 $item_name = $_POST["item_name"];
 $item_code = $_POST["item_code"];
 $item_desc = $_POST["item_desc"];
 $item_price = $_POST["item_price"];
 $item_time = $_POST["item_time"];
 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($item_name); $count++)
 {
  $item_name_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_name[$count]);
  $item_code_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_code[$count]);
  $item_desc_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_desc[$count]);
  $item_price_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_price[$count]);
  $item_time_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_time[$count]);
  if($item_name_clean != '' && $item_code_clean != '' && $item_desc_clean != '' && $item_price_clean != '' && $item_time_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO item2(item_name, item_code, item_desc, item_price, item_time) 
   VALUES("'.$item_name_clean.'", "'.$item_code_clean.'", "'.$item_desc_clean.'", "'.$item_price_clean.'", "'.$item_time_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Item Data Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All Fields are Required';
 }
}
?>

<?php
//insert3.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if(isset($_POST["nombre_proyecto"]))
{
 $nombre_proyecto = $_POST["nombre_proyecto"];
 $descripcion_proyecto = $_POST["descripcion_proyecto"];
 $supervisor_proyecto = $_POST["supervisor_proyecto"];
 $tiempo_proyecto = $_POST["tiempo_proyecto"];
 $costo_proyecto = $_POST["costo_proyecto"];
 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($nombre_proyecto); $count++)
 {
  $nombre_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $nombre_proyecto[$count]);
  $descripcion_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $descripcion_proyecto[$count]);
  $supervisor_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $supervisor_proyecto[$count]);
  $tiempo_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $tiempo_proyecto[$count]);
  $costo_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $costo_proyecto[$count]);
  if($nombre_proyecto_clean != '' && $descripcion_proyecto_clean != '' && $supervisor_proyecto_clean != '' && $tiempo_proyecto_clean != '' && $costo_proyecto_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO item3(nombre_proyecto, descripcion_proyecto, supervisor_proyecto, tiempo_proyecto, costo_proyecto) 
   VALUES("'.$nombre_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$descripcion_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$supervisor_proyecto_clean .'", "'.$tiempo_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$costo_proyecto_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Item Data Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All Fields are Required';
 }
}
?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, agradezco la atención.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

siguiendo tu planteamiento lo primero que te sugiero es que renombres las tablas de la BD porfa item tiem1 item2 etc es una locura, pero bueno es tu código, en relación a tu pregunta y siguiendo el planteamiento (por lo que entendí) primero en la tabla donde guardas el proyecto agregale un campo int que sea autoincrement y que sea la clave primarya, en las demas tablas agrega uno que se llame id_proyecto y que sea clave foranea, asi mantienes una relación de tablas, y siempre que crees un proyecto lo primero que tienes que hacer es primero hacer el insert en la tabla de los proyectos, una vez hecho al ser autoincrement haces un

```
select id_proyecto from proyectos order by id_proyecto desc limit
```

eso te dara el ultimo registro, lo guardas en una variable y acto seguro haces el insert de las siguientes tablas pasandole en id de proyecto al campo id_proyecto de las demás tabla.. seria algo como esto.

```
'INSERT INTO item3(id_proyecto,nombre_proyecto, descripcion_proyecto, supervisor_proyecto,   tiempo_proyecto, costo_proyecto) 
  VALUES(0,"'.$nombre_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$descripcion_proyecto_clean.'",   "'.$supervisor_proyecto_clean .'", "'.$tiempo_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$costo_proyecto_clean.'"); '; 

 // haces tus comprobaciones que todo se ha insertado etc y luego haces
 select id_proyecto from item3 order by id_proyecto desc limit 1;
 //Te guardas el resultado en una variable $id_proyecto y en los siguientes insert

 'INSERT INTO item(item_act, item_tipo, item_desca, item_timea, item_respa,id_proyecto) 
  VALUES("'.$item_act_clean.'", "'.$item_tipo_clean.'", "'.$item_desca_clean.'",    "'.$item_timea_clean.'", "'.$item_respa_clean.'",$id_proyecto);';


'INSERT INTO item2(item_name, item_code, item_desc, item_price,  item_time,id_proyecto) 
 VALUES("'.$item_name_clean.'", "'.$item_code_clean.'", "'.$item_desc_clean.'", $item_price_clean.'", "'.$item_time_clean.'",$id_proyecto);';
```

si son script separado que creo que es el caso guarda el valor de id_proyecto en una variable de session por ejemplo..
espero esto se valga..
saludos

Comment: Antes que nada, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Seguiré tu consejo sobre el nombre de las tablas. Y en efecto, tengo mis página PHP que hacen la conexión e insertan los datos, por separado (una para cada formulario). Sólo que tengo una duda (soy nuevo en esto) y es la siguiente: ¿Cómo podría guardar el valor del último id del proyecto en una variable de sesión? y ¿cómo haría el registro de ese valor recuperado en la base de datos de cada formulario? Agradezco muchísimo tu apoyo! Saludos.

Comment: De nada, a ver hay algo que no me queda claro, los formularios se enviar por separado?? o sea al darle al boton save que acciòn realizas?? creas el proyecto o creas todo a la vez, es para ayudarte con más claridad y las variable de session tienes que poner en cada uno de los script session_start() y cuando recuperes el id_proyecto en lugar de $id_proyecto=20; haces $_SESSION['id_pryecto']=20; y donde te puse $id_proyecto en el codigo, sustituyelo por la variable de session

Comment: Gracias, por la información. Exactamente, se envían por separado pero al mismo tiempo se guardan los tres formularios al dar clic en save.

Comment: áun asi no me queda claro, si tu le das al save(salvo que sea asyncrono) tiene que ir al action de un form (o al propio script si no defines uno) describeme la secuencia que haces, ejemplo, das save y se crea el proyecto etc, pq sigo sin entender como ejecutas 3 form en 3 script distinto simultaneamente

Comment: Así es, activa los 3 form el botón "save" y por lo cual, se realiza la inserción de los registros en cada tabla. Realmente no realiza ningún registro primero, si no, que todos al mismo tiempo. Esto lo logré gracias a las últimas líneas de código del HTML (no inserto aquí por falta de espacio) que realmente son scripts ejecutables.

Comment: perdona no habia visto el codigo entero, es que estas usando ajax, y si tienen una secuencia, tienes 3 llamadas ajax con el evento click y se ejecuta primero insert2, insert y insert3, cambia el orden para que primero sea el 3, se cree el proyecto y en el sucess del ajax recojas el id_deproyecto una vez insertado, y se lo pasas a los siguientes llamadas y lleven el parametro a los siguientes script

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probaré a ver si me funciona, aunque no me queda muy claro como recoger el dato del id_proyecto. Lo intentaré agregando lo que me has mencionado en las páginas php de insert.

Answer (score 2):

Tu lo que buscas es guardar la referencia al proyecto al que pertenecen para los materiales y actividades. Es un tema de **diseño entidad-relación de la base de datos**. Creo que el código que aportas (CSS y PHP) no sirve para resolver tu consulta, salvo las *queries* que nos dan información sobre los datos que quieres guardar.

Voy a crear un esquema sencillo de 3 tablas, para que te sirva como guía: *proyectos*, *materiales* y *actividades*, cuyos registros solo van a tener un ID, nombre y las claves foráneas necesarias.

Primero veamos cómo relacionar las entidades. Una posible solución sería un proyecto puede tener una o muchas actividades y una actividad uno o muchos materiales, asimismo un material puede usarse para una o muchas actividades. El esquema E-R inicial sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de ahí se entiende que vamos a necesitar una nueva tabla que relacione actividades y materiales ya que tienen una relación de muchos a muchos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora es el momento de crear las tablas. Un proyecto es la base, ya que puede haber varias actividades relacionadas con un proyecto, por lo que en actividades hay una FK a proyectos. La tabla *proyectos* se crea *primero, seguidamente la tabla *actividades* que tiene una FK apuntando a *proyectos*. Luego *materiales* y finalmente la tabla que representa la relación de muchos a muchos: *material_actividad*.

- En realidad puedes crear en primer lugar cualquier tabla que no tenga FK hacia otras tablas, por ejemplo *materiales*.

#### SQL:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test.projects` (
  `id_project` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL
);

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test.activities` (
  `id_activity` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `project_id` INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_activities_to_projects`
    FOREIGN KEY (`project_id` )
    REFERENCES `test.projects` (`id_project`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test.materials` (
  `id_material` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL
);

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test.material_activity` (
  `id_material_activity` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `activity_id` INT NULL,
  `material_id` INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_to_activities`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id` )
    REFERENCES `test.activities` (`id_activity`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_to_materials`
    FOREIGN KEY (`material_id` )
    REFERENCES `test.materials` (`id_material`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Con lo que te queda la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creadas las tablas puedes crear *proyectos* y *materiales* de forma "independiente". Las actividades debes relacionarlas con un proyecto, aunque puedes crearlas sin asignar la referencia que tomará el valor *null*. Ahora cuando haces la selección de que pertenece a qué: materiales que pertenecen a cada actividad y actividades de un proyecto, es cuando creas registros en la tabla *material_actividad*, para el primer caso y seteas la id del proyecto en cada registro de la tabla de *actividades* para asignarlas a un proyecto determinado.

**El diseño E-R puede variar**, según la solución que necesitas, por ejemplo, la relación entre *actividades* y *proyectos* puede ser también de muchos a muchos.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la información, pero resulta que mi problema es más sencillo, ya que, no busco que haya una relación material-actividad, aunque ahora gracias a tu valiosa información, sé como realizarlo. Aunque me surge la duda de que si solamente creando esas relaciones en la base de datos, el código php detectará automáticamente el id del proyecto y lo repetirá en los "n" registros de actividades o materiales que desee realizar. Ya que, hemos intentado con esas relaciones (creándolas desde el modo diseñador) y hemos fracasado. Agradezco tu atención! Saludos.